# Change font size of label with data defined expression in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am trying to change the font size of the feature labels based on attributes from a field.  I can't find an example of how to do this.

I believe I can do this by setting up a data defined expression in the `Labels`>`Text`>`Size` expression but I am not sure how to formulate the actual expression.

I am looking for an example of how this expression would be set up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In @mgri 's answer "font_height" will need to give a valid value for the size field (i.e. a number or number-like string). If it is a number you can simply use `"font_height"` as the expression. If not you will need to do something with the value. If "font_height" had values of 'big', 'medium' and 'small' you would need to use some conditional logic:

```
CASE
    WHEN "font_height" = 'big' THEN 14
    WHEN "font_height" = 'medium' THEN 10
    WHEN "font_height" = 'small' THEN 8
END
```

Alternatively, if "font_height" values were something like '14pt' you would need to something like:

```
replace("font_height", 'pt', '')
```

Comment: +1 Good point, I think that Caitlin knows all the possible situations by now! =)

Comment: Thank you to mgri, George of all trades, and Knightshound.  I implemented the above code and it works great!  Thanks again, Caitlin

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, go on the `Layer Properties` > `Labels` > `Text` window.

Then, edit the expression for the text size (I marked it in the image below):

[image]

In the expression field, simply write the name of the field which stores the sizes for the fonts of the labels. In my case, the field was called `font_height`, so I wrote (remember to use these `" "`):

[image]

Finally, click on the Apply button and this will be the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to mgri's answer, you can use CASE WHEN at the same location:

```
CASE WHEN [column-A] = [something] THEN 3
     WHEN [column-A] = [something else] THEN 4
     ELSE 5
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another addition: It is possible to store a CASE statement like this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN @map_scale < 100000 THEN 18  
  WHEN @map_scale < 1000000 THEN 16
  WHEN @map_scale < 10000000 THEN 14
  ELSE 12           
END
```

in a project variable, e.g. my_font_size, and then use the expression EVAL(@my_font_size) as a data defined override for a font size

```
enter code here
```